# Where can I get comdef.h?

Tags: c++

I downloaded some example code from the internet, but when I compiled it I ran into some trouble. My compiler tells me: comdef.h: No such file or directory.

I searched a bit on the internet, but I couldn't find anyone else with the same problem and I have no clue where I can obtain this header file.

I use codeblocks with the GNU GCC compiler.

Answer (score 4):

The file is available with Visual Studio (not sure you have to install Platform SDK). You can get [comdef.h](http://doc.ddart.net/msdn/header/include/comdef.h.html) from the Web but for sure you will have some troubles getting it to compile with your sources.

Comment: comdef.h comes with Visual C++/Visual Studio (part of the compiler's "built-in COM support"). There is no relationship to the Platform SDK as far as I know.

Comment: Ok Chris that was my initial understanding.

Answer (score 3):

As other posters have said, `comdef.h` comes with Visual C++. It supplements the VC-specific builtin COM support. Since you say you're using GCC, you will probably have to adapt your code to use "low-level COM", since GCC doesn't have the kind of builtin COM support that VC has (in specific, using `#import` for importing type libraries into convenient wrapper classes).

Answer (score -2):

The file should be available after installing the Microsoft Platform SDK. Don't know how well it works with GNU GCC though.

http://www.microsoft.com/msdownload/platformsdk/sdkupdate/